# Python Zybooks lab issue

Tags: python-3.x

A common year in the modern Gregorian Calendar consists of 365 days. In reality, Earth takes longer to rotate around the sun. To account for the difference in time, every 4 years, a leap year takes place. A leap year is when a year has 366 days: An extra day, February 29th. The requirements for a given year to be a leap year are:

1. The year must be divisible by 4
2. If the year is a century year (1700, 1800, etc.), the year must be evenly divisible by 400; therefore, both 1700 and 1800 are not leap years

Some example leap years are 1600, 1712, and 2016.

Write a program that takes in a year and determines the number of days in February for that year.

Ex: If the input is:

1712
the output is:

1712 has 29 days in February.
Ex: If the input is:

1913
the output is:

1913 has 28 days in February.

I am working on this zyBooks lab, and everything checks out while testing. The issue is when I submit I get an error :TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable. Here is my code:

```
def days_in_feb(year):
    if '00' in year:
        if int(year) % 400 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
                 
    if int(year) % 4 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    year = input()
    feb = days_in_feb(year)
    if days_in_feb(year) is True:
        print(f'{year} has 29 days in February.') 
    else:
        print(f'{year} has 28 days in February.')
```

It seems the auto grader doesnt like the way I have things arranged, but I am new to python so I couldnt tell you where it things its trying to iterate other than "if '00' in year"

Comment: Do you have the full traceback of the error? If you do, please include it in the question. It might give you an idea which line the error resides.

Comment: The error does not call out what line the error is generated on. Thats what makes me think the the auto grader is causing it.

Comment: Did you submit the entire script or just the `days_in_feb function`? Depending on how the auto grader is set up, you might not have submitted what it was expecting.